# React Native TypeScript Project: Carousel Implementation Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm working on a React Native project using TypeScript and trying to implement a carousel feature. I've attempted to use react-native-snap-carousel, but I'm encountering several errors, including "Cannot read property 'array' of undefined" and "Invariant Violation: 'main' has not been registered". These errors persist despite ensuring Metro is run in the correct directory and all components are correctly registered with AppRegistry.registerComponent.

Error Messages:

```
    ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'array' of undefined, js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
    * Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
    * A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
```

I use this [tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/implement-react-native-snap-carousel/) : https://blog.logrocket.com/implement-react-native-snap-carousel/

and add `import CarouselCards from '../CarouselCards';` and `<CarouselCards />` to my home page.

Thank you for your help !